# Filter results containing drive paths by parent paths in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains mappings of UserIds to some paths on disk (e.g. `\\UNCserver\path` or `C:\user\has\a\folder`). I control the data and there is no trailing `\` symbols in the DB.

Periodically, I need to select user IDs that have a parent path of the path in question assigned. E.g. if I have an event in `\\superserver\cluster\2`, I want to get *all* user IDs that have *either or all* of the following paths:

```
\\superserver\cluster\2
\\superserver\cluster
\\superserver
```

I have a stored procedure that does just that, but it is extremely inefficient due to the operations on the string that I use - for just 10000 UserPaths records I can load CPU to 50% invoking this just a few hundred of times in a row.

How can I optimise this procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectUserIdsWithPath]
    @Path nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF (@Path IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
DECLARE @TempPath NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @TempPath = SUBSTRING(@Path, 0, LEN(@Path) + 1 - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@Path)))
        IF (LEN(@Path) - LEN(REPLACE(@Path, '\', '')) = 1) --we need to process path C:\
        BEGIN
            SET @TempPath = @TempPath + '\';
        END
        INSERT INTO Results(UserId)
        SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM UserPaths
        WHERE 
        UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM Results)
        AND (Path = @Path 
            OR CHARINDEX(Path, @TempPath, 0) <> 0)
    END
END
```

**UPDATE** I have now changed the logic in my app so that figuring out the parent path is done in the app, which may have improved things a bit, but performance is still pathetic. Here is updated proc listing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectUserIdsWithPath]
        @Path NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ParentPath NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@Path IS NOT NULL AND @ParentPath IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Results(UserId)
            SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM UserPaths
            WHERE 
            UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM Results)
            AND (Path = @Path 
                OR CHARINDEX(Path, @ParentPath, 0) <> 0)
        END
    END
```

So the culprit is obviously `CHARINDEX()` call. Unfortunately I am still waiting on the infrastructure to confirm if we can turn Full-Text indexing on, but are there any alternatives?

Comment: Are you sure the SP is giving you the expected result. From what I see it only checks for `\superserver\cluster\2` and `\superserver\cluster` but not `\superuser`. Anyway, are you able to re-design you database? I think that storing the path decomposed would allow you to do it in more SQL-like way.

Comment: TomT not really, if i dissect paths when i store them then i lose in processing time there :( Also, i will run some more tests but preliminary this CHARINDEX(Path, @TempPath, 0) <> 0) covered all uses cases, it's just that i couldnt use only that as it returned false postiives for \\server\path\path1 if i submit \\server\path\path11.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a cte to extract the parent folders. Something like this:

```
create procedure SelectUserIdsWithPath


@path varchar(250)
as begin

With c
As
(Select cast(path as varchar(500)) path
from (Select @path path) t
Union all select 
Cast(substring(path,0,len(path)-charindex('\',reverse(path),0)+1) as varchar(500))
From c 
where charindex('\',reverse(substring(path,0,len(path)-charindex('\',reverse(path),0)+1) ),0)>1)

Select distinct userid from userpaths up where exists(select * from c where c.path=up.path)

end
```

Comment: isn't that going to be even slower than a basic charindex in my update?

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your post. if you pass in '\superserver\cluster\2', do you want to match '\superserver\cluster\3'? If so, then my example would not be  correct. but if you want to match only the original path and each parent path, then this example would correct and you wouldn't have to use 'like' or do character searching. if you throw an index on path on your userpaths table, it would be extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you need Full Text Search; 10k rows is a fairly small amount.  There are probably a few things going on here that are affecting performance to varying degrees.

Any examples below are based on the original proc (as that should have been fine), but could easily be adapted to the updated proc by simply changing @TempPath to be @ParentPath.

1. Not a performance issue, but SQL Server start indexes are 1, not 0. 
   So the SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX should be using 1 instead of 0.
2. Why are you using NVARCHAR(MAX)? If you know that none of your paths are
   over 4000 characters, you would be better off using NVARCHAR(4000)
   for the input parameter datatype as well as local variable datatype.
3. The two fields in the [CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) appear to be transposed as the
   signature is:
   `CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ ,
   start_location ] )`.
   So it should be: `CHARINDEX(@TempPath, Path)`.
4. It does not appear that you need CHARINDEX anyway. You should be just fine with:
   `[Path] = @TempPath
   OR [Path] LIKE @TempPath + N'\%'`
   Note that @TempPath is now used in both conditions.
   If using the original proc then be sure to remove the `IF (LEN(@Path)...BEGIN...END` else don't bother adding the trailing \ to @ParentPath in the app code (for the C:\ case). In either case, a LIKE is probably better than CHARINDEX as LIKE with a trailing '%' and no leading '%' is basically a `String.StartsWith` while CHARINDEX is a `String.Contains`.
5. The SELECT for the INSERT could maybe be improved by separating out the DISTINCT and the NOT IN into a second query, using a temp table to hold the results from the first query:
   `INSERT INTO #TempResults(UserId)
       SELECT UserId
       FROM UserPaths
       WHERE [Path] = @TempPath
       OR [Path] LIKE @TempPath + N'\%'`

   `INSERT INTO Results(UserId)
       SELECT DISTINCT UserId
       FROM #TempResults
       WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM Results)`
   You should test the NOT IN condition in both queries to see where it works better.
6. Given that this proc is called "hundreds of times a minute" (via Service Broker) and that the **Results** table "gets cleared out around every minute": if at all possible, move the expensive operation (i.e. guaranteeing uniqueness of UserId via the DISTINCT and NOT IN subquery) away from the process that runs hundreds of times per minute to the operation that runs about once per minute. So, a) remove the Unique Constraint on the **Results** table, b) update the process that consumes the **Results** table to include the DISTINCT, and c) use the following, simplified INSERT...SELECT:
   `INSERT INTO Results(UserId)
       SELECT UserId
       FROM UserPaths
       WHERE [Path] = @TempPath
       OR [Path] LIKE @TempPath + N'\%'`
   If Service Broker is configured to run this proc via multiple threads, then you are also experiencing contention between the INSERT operations and the SELECT for the NOT IN subquery. This contention will be avoided by the removal of the NOT IN subquery.
   *[I will update the WHERE condition after getting clarification on how to determine valid matches]*

Comment: 1. Thanks for that, didn't know that
2. Would there be a performance improvement by limiting the size of NVARCHAR? i have no idea how long the paths would be (immediately they're limited at 248 characters by Windows, but i am not sure if we're not going to support paths longer by making them virtual)
3. So if i do CHARINDEX(@TempPath, Path) then Path 'C:\' for @TempPath 'C:\Bananas' returns 0 (c:\bananas not found in c:\), whereas if i swap them it is 1 (what i need)

Comment: 4. This might actually work, let me try that.
5. i thought temp tables would not work well for me - i am calling this hundreds of times a minute? teardown of temptable may be costly.

Comment: tried with LIKE, doesn't sem to work. So for instance:
User has C:\ path. The proc is invoked for C:\folder1\subfolder1. User DOES match. Another user has C:\folder1 path. This user matches also. A third one has C:\folder10 path. This one DOES NOT match. A fourth one has C:\folder1\subfolder11. This one DOES NOT match.

Comment: @zaitsman: for #1, no prob. So far no harm done as 0 is the same as using 1 for the Start Position. And when calculating Length for the SUBSTRING there is no diff between a 0-based and 1-based array. But if you were to calculate the Start Position assuming a 0-based array, then you would get erroneous results. A string of 'abc' and wanting the 'bc', passing in 1 as the Start Position would get back 'abc', not 'bc'.

Comment: @zaitsman: For #2, yes it can make a diff. So try making just that one change (both input params and local variable) and see if there is a difference in speed. Yes, Windows technically allows for up to 32k, but is that realistic? Even 2560 is a 10x increase from the base 256 limit. Assuming NVARCHAR(4000) performs better, go with that until there is a need for NVARCHAR(MAX). [will post more later]

Comment: @zaitsman: for #5, that is a high volume of calls, but it a DISTINCT is an expensive operation. This is something that is easy to test by having two procs where the only difference is the 2 query & temp vable vs the current 1 query approach. However, this does bring up a few questions: how many rows are in the **Results** table, does it get cleared out, and is it 1 or more threads of an app calling this proc hundreds of times per minute? There might be more we can do depending on the answers to these three.

Comment: i'll try limiting variable length and try without distinct. The Results table will accept as many userid's as returned by this proc, it has a unique constraint on the userId column, it gets cleared out around every minute. It is the Service Broker queue that is calling this proc. My multiple app threads are calling the proc that will send the message to the service to activate the queue, which invokes the proc in question. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @zaitsman: for #3 & #4, I am confused about what a valid match is. The description "select user ids that have a parent path of the path in question" implies that 'C:\folder1\subfolder11' matches Path='C:\folder1\subfolder1' because they share 'C:\folder1'. The code you have only removes the last folder so it tries to match on 'C:\folder1' for TempPath so 'C:\' would never match anyway and 'C:\folder11' will match (if we use the code as a guide). Can you please provide a chart showing valid & invalid cases, for UNC and local paths, and a Path (not TempPath) value of 'C:\P1\P2\P3\P4' ?

Comment: @zaitsman: In either case, a LIKE is probably better than CHARINDEX as LIKE without a leading '%' is basically a StartsWith while CHARINDEX is a Contains. And if the **UserPaths** table can have more than 1 of the same UserId, then you still need the DISTINCT; I was just moving it away from the SELECT that was doing the string compare to see if that would help.